# Launching "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger" without prompting

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have set up my system to automatically attach the visual studio debugger when a certain application is launched using these instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28printer%29.aspx

The problem is that I get a dialog box each time that requires me to confirm that I do indeed want to attach the debugger. The dialog also prompts me to specify which visual studio debugger I want to attach (I have VS2003, VS2005 and VS2008 installed on the system). I've selected "New instance of Visual Studio 2008" and checked the "Set the currently selected debugger as default."-box but the dialog keeps popping up.

Thanks

Andreas Brinck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a registry entry that determines how the debugger is started. Under

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

create a DWORD value named "Auto" with a value of 1, so no confirmation window displays